# I'm trying to retrieve an array of maps from my firebase - flutter app but its stuck at StreamBuilder if snapshot.hasdata and keep loading indicator

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

this is how im retrieving data in StreamBuilder

```
Stream<List<Patient>> get getAllPatients{

return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Patients').snapshots().map(patientsListFromQuerySnapShot);
}
```

Patients Model

```
class Patient {
  String id,
      name,
      country,
      nationality,
      treatment,
      createdTime,
      addedBy,
  Map<String, dynamic> payments;
  bool paymentStatus;
  int paidAmount, phone;
```

patientsListFromQuerySnapShot method :

```
  List<Patient>  patientsListFromQuerySnapShot(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot){

    return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Patient(
        id: doc['id'],
        treatment: doc['treatment'],
        name: doc['name'],
        country: doc['country'],
        paymentStatus: doc['paymentStatus'],
        phone: doc['phone'],
        payments: doc['payments'],
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

commenting out the 'payments: doc['payments']' line makes the StreamBuilder works and get the data but i cant retrieve the payments list of maps which includes {payment date : '' , paid amount: ''}
[image]

My StreamBuilder

```
return Scaffold(
  drawer: AdminNavigationDrawer(),
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('All Patients'),
  ),
  body: StreamBuilder<List<Patient>>(
    stream: FirebaseApi().getAllPatients,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        var data = snapshot.data;
        return Column(
          children: [
            buildSearch(),
            query == ''
                ? buildAllPatients(data)
                : filteredPatientsNum(data: data).length != 0
                    ? buildFilteredPatients(data)
                    : Center(
                        child: Text('No Patients Found'),
                      ),
          ],
        );
      }
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: post the stream builder, post your parts of code.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad i posted the StreamBuilder too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to assign a List to a Map

change your Patient Model

```
class Patient {
  String id,
      name,
      country,
      nationality,
      treatment,
      createdTime,
      addedBy,
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> payments;
  bool paymentStatus;
  int paidAmount, phone;
```

and then parse payments like this

```
payments: List<Map<String,dyanmic>>.from(doc['payments']),
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve it?

```
payments: List<Map<String,dyanmic>>.from(doc['payments']),
```

What is the error you are getting before commenting it out.

Comment: This gives me an error of "A value of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' "   

the error before was getting stuck at the loading indicator and not getting data from the streamBuilder , converting the payments to a list of map<String , dynamic> solved the problem